# Reverse proxy nginx port 443 to Node App with SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I have setup my express & node app to use my letsencrypt ssl certs as so

```
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem')
};

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(3060);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(3061);
```

I can reach my API at domain.com (hitting port 80 in nginx)

But I can't reach it if I hit https://example.com (port 443)

However I can reach it if I open up port 3061 and request https://example.com:3061 and it works correctly with SSL

**My question is, how do I setup nginx to correctly forward requests on port 443 to my server on port 3061 for SSL.**

Do I need to include the cert information as suggested elsewhere, if my app is dealing with it?

My nginx config is like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3060;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}   

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:3061;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK `nginx` cannot pass-through SSL connections, it needs to terminate them.

Comment: what do you get trying to access https://example.com and what does nginx log?

Comment: @Kristianmitk: While accessing `https://example.com/api/users` I get the following in `error.log`

`[error] 7969#0: *192726 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <IP_ADDR>, server: example.com, request: "GET /api/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3060/api/users", host: "example.com"`

While accessing example.com/api/users the following in `access.log`

`"GET /api/users HTTP/1.1" 502 583 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"`